# Is it possible to run VB windows applications which used Mathematica .NET/Link, without mathematica?

Tags: vb.net, wolfram-mathematica, mathlink

I want to develop a program using VB.Net 2010, and I want to use Mathematica 3DPlot functions via .NET/Link. My problem is that is it possible to run that program in another computer without Mathematica installed?.
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this is not possible, no .

Comment: [MathLink is just an interface to the Mathematica kernel](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/IntroductionToMathLink.html) (third paragraph)

Comment: Dear Rolf and all, So, How can I create a redistributable package for my program, including .NET/link and mathematica kernal?

Comment: @user1169249 buy Wolfram Research, write your own compatible mathkernel, or perhaps blackmail.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: be nice ! Fact is that with Matlab you can build (easily) standalone appliactions (http://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/index.html). With Mathematica you can only create standalone C-code which does not have to call back to the Mathematica kernel. I think that this is the one important reason Mathematica is not used in production as much as it could be ...

Comment: I am nice, which I why I both voted for your answer and provided options in an answer below. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I believe that your only options for redistributable *Mathematica* functionality are:

1. [Wolfram CDF Player](http://www.wolfram.com/cdf-player/) and all the limitations that go along with it.
2. Make a net app and use [webMathematica](http://www.wolfram.com/products/webmathematica/) on either your own or hosted servers, where you will pay for all CPU cycles.

Comment: CDF player is not option to my problem. I want to do calculations and plot 3d graphs. Webmathematica is nice, but my project is not web based.

Comment: @user I expected as much, but that's all I can offer. I think the lack of a way to redistribute programs is probably the one biggest downside to using *Mathematica*.  CDF helps a bit, but it's not really for applications and utilities but rather presentations.